# Deploy React-App and Express API on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, vercel

Hey im trying to deploy my Express app to the provider Vercel.
This is my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
const cors = require('cors')

const PORT = 3002;
const app = express();


app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: process.env.REACT_APP_URL
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./build")));




app.get("/api/tasks", async (req,res) =>{
    //const jsonArray = await csv.readAll('tasks.csv');
    res.send([{a: 'a'}]);
});


app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(
      path.join(__dirname, "./build/index.html")
   );
});

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
  console.log(`Server is running on ` + PORT);
})

module.exports = app
```

it works fine in development. I get ./build/index.html served on "/" and can make a request to "/api/tasks". However after deploying to Vercel the request stopped working but i could still see index.html. I tryed a little bit around and after adding a vercel.json:

```
{
"builds": [
    {
        "src": "index.js",
        "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
],
"routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "index.js"
    }
]
```

}

the request worked but then the index.html didnt got served. I think i need to change something in the vercel.json but i have no clue.

https://tasksapp-ten.vercel.app/        <--- no index.html
https://tasksapp-ten.vercel.app/api/tasks <---- works fine